# iBATOR classPathEntry, can it be set as relative to the project?

Tags: java, ibatis

When following this tutorial the one thing I really have a question on is the classPathEntry: http://blog.agdunn.net/?p=313

Notice his entry is hard wired to the full path of the mysql-connector jar:

Is there a way to specify the project root as a variable in this type of situation?

example:

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question?! Do you want to know if you can eliminate to absolute specified path to the mysql-connector?

If so, the [ibator documentation](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/tools/ibator/) is of help. [From the docs](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/tools/ibator/configreference/classPathEntry.html):

> The `<classPathEntry>` Element
>
> This element is optional and is not required if you setup the classpath externally to Ibator (e.g. with the -cp argument of the java command.

Which indicates you can do without if you are adding the mysql-connector somewhere else to the classpath, for example your startup script.

Comment: But either way I will have to have an absolute path? I am trying to avoid absolute paths so that this project can be highly portable... less little things to remember the better.

Comment: No, you do not necessarily need an absolute path.  I do not know how your application is started, but if your mysql.jar is packed with your application, then you can specify the relative path.  I suppose you have more jar-files bundled; I suggest you put the mysql.jar there as well.